# ue4editor.exe GPU selection

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

Even though I set ue4editor.exe to use integrated graphics on my laptop, it somehow ends up using the discrete nvidia gpu; is there a way to set the preferred gpu with the unreal suite?

Comment: This sounds like a tech support question to direct to the makers of this software, who don't necessarily monitor this website.

Comment: @DMGregory Maybe some user encountered the same problem and there may be a configuration parameter somewhere(I am new to unreal engine)

Comment: Perhaps this may help you https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/12727/editor-crashes-on-launch.html

Comment: @ColdSteel Thanks for the info. That explains it; they are using the higher spec gpu regardless of optimus setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a console variable for that:
r.GraphicsAdapter

you can set in Engine.ini or DefaultEngine.ini

Comment: Someone know where exactly ? I put it to `Config\DefaultEngine.ini` at the beginning of the file. But that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `r.GraphicsAdapter=1` ( Choosing device 1 ) to `<Your Unreal Projects Folder>\Unreal Projects\MyProject5\Config\DefaultEngine.ini` inside the section `[/Script/Engine.RendererSettings]`.

Eg.:

###### Unreal Projects\MyProject5\Config\DefaultEngine.ini

```
[/Script/HardwareTargeting.HardwareTargetingSettings]
; quality settings
TargetedHardwareClass=Desktop
AppliedTargetedHardwareClass=Desktop
DefaultGraphicsPerformance=Maximum
AppliedDefaultGraphicsPerformance=Maximum


[/Script/Engine.RendererSettings]
r.GraphicsAdapter=1
; exposure control and tone mapping settings
r.Tonemapper.Sharpen=2
r.TemporalAA.Upsampling=True
...
```

Comment: Seems not to work always. Is there a magic trick to see which GPU is used inside Unreal Editor ?

Comment: Found out it is easiest to use the Task manager Performance View and check there the performance usage of the different GPUs.